# Too many websockets open with Binance node api

Tags: vue.js, websocket, binance

Im using node-binance-api.

And Im opening the websocket on creation of the Vue.js page.

```
 created(){
      client2.ws.futuresTicker(this.ticker, ticker => {
       that.currentPrice = ticker.curDayClose
     })
  }
```

This opens the websocket.  But after a while I have like 20 - 30 price updates occuring, as if the websockets aren't being closed.

Sometimes if I refresh the page it works.  But sometimes refreshing the page doesnt get rid of the problem.

Is there a way to specifically close the socket??

Ive tried

```
  client2.ws.close()
```

But thats not available.

Comment: Can you check whats the ready state while component is being destroyed? 
`onDestroy() { console.log(client2.ws.readyState) }`